# VBscript craches when mentioning the CodePage with an ASP 203 error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, migration, iis-7.5, codepages

I have an ASP page beginning with a VBscript like this :

```
<%@ Language=VBScript CodePage=iso-8859-1%>
<% ...
```

This code worked fine with IIS6 under W2K but when migrating to windows 2008 with IIS7.5, I get this error :

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0203'

Invalid Code Page

/path/to/my_page.asp, line 1

The specified code page attribute is invalid.
```

When removing the CodePage, everything worked normaly. Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: Should really use quotes around the attributes. I have to ask, why are you using the Latin code page and not UTF-8 (65001)?

Comment: I just have to migrate asp pages from iis6 to 7.5 I didn't choose that..

Comment: Even with quotes.. same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Codepage` parameter does only support numbers, e.g.:

```
<%@Codepage = 65001 %>
```

You can see a table of valid values [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx). Use this number for ISO-8859-1:

```
<%@Codepage = 28591 %>
```

Comment: I would assume, that IIS 7.5 uses a more strict parser. IIS 6 probably simply ignored the parameter silently and used the default codepage.